# Skip the element and search in child

Tags: xml, xslt

Lets say I have an element A which has child elements B and C. I want to check if ELement A has a specific attribute in it. If not, skip A and check B for the same(Which is the child of A) and then check C as well for the particular Attribute. Is that possible? To skip the elements with the missing attribute and select only the ones with the attributes available in **XSLT?**

Comment: `A[@foo]` selects only `A` elements with a `foo` attribute. Skipping is usually done in XSLT by using only `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, obviously then for `match="A[not(@foo)]"`.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this? I am new to xslt . If you could explain it more simply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the presence or absence of the attwearelookingfor is the trigger, but the logic can besswitched around:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@attwearelookingfor>
    <!-- the attribute is not here, so check the child elements -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- the attribute is here, so stop -->
      <p>do something else</p>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

(fwiw 'choose' is more verbose but catches all tests)

Comment: This is very awkward: 1. Use `xsl:choose` for mutually exclusive conditions; 2. Use `test="mynode"` or `test="not(mynode)"` to test the existence or absence of a node.